# QT Apps like GRSYNC and VLC starts slowly on Ubuntu 20.4 (since some time)

Tags: qt, grsync

i'm on Ubuntustudio 20.4 and i'm using grsync to backup my data. This was working fine since I installed Ubuntu, but now grsync takes over 30s to start. I tried via the terminal and from the start menu with the same long loading time. I installed appmenu-gtk2-module as suggested here:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2441572

but there's no improvement. Also Chromium is starting quite slowly when starting it the first time after a boot. When starting it a second time it comes up fast. However Grsync starts always slow and this problem started maybe some weeks ago (was not using grsync for some time). I figured out that it basically affects all QT apps.

My distro:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

with XFCE. Does this also affect other users? If so, I likely have to wait until the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why exactly, but now it works again. I installed appmenu-gtk3-module (0.7.3-2), appmenu-registrar (0.7.3-2) and vala-panel-appmenu-common (0.7.3+dfsg1-2) and deninstalled appmenu-gtk2-module. When starting grsync there was an error that appmenu-gtk2-module could not be loaded.  After reinstalling appmenu-gtk2-module grsync and VLC are starting fast again.

Answer (score 0):

I did

```
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
```

and

```
sudo apt install appmenu-gtk2-module
```

and rebooted. Now grsync loads instantly.